# Ошибка «(кракозябры) не является внутренней или внешней командой»

Tags: bat, echo, for

> 1. Определение размера  ICMP-пакетов.
>
> Подобрать значение длины пакетов, чтобы не было сообщений ошибках пакетов.  Для этого в текстовом редакторе создать командный файл proba.bat следующего содержания:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> for /L %%i in (1000#,100#,100000#) do (
> for /F «usebackq delims=< tokens=2» %%a IN (`ping -l %%i 127.0.0.1 -n 1`) DO@echo Размербуфера отправки=%%i……Время отклика=%%a)
> ```
>
> *(Вместо `«»` нужно ставить кавычки `""`, и выходит то что на скрине, без них консоль быстро закрывается)*

Выходит следующая картина:

[image: Ошибка]

> 2. Подобрать значение длины пакетов, чтобы не было сообщений  ошибках при фрагментации пакетов.
>
> В текстовом редакторе создать командный  файл proba_2.bat следующего содержания:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> for /L %%i in (1000#,1#,10000#) do (
> for /F «skip=2 usebackq delims=< tokens=2» %%a IN (`ping -f -l %%i 127.0.0.1 -n 1`) DO @echo Размербуфера отправки=%%i……Время отклика=%%a)
> ```

Картина такая же, консоль выдает что «не является внутренней или внешней».

Comment: Батчи следует сохранять в 866 кодовой.

Comment: Так я думаю дело не в кодировке

Comment: Исправил кодировку, но всё так не находит команду

Comment: код правильный, а что это у вас там за символы после `=%%i`? убирайте всё лишнее и в сохранённой кодировке 866 работает... работает в любой просто читать не удобно))) а в первом случае вам пишут что  `Размер буфера отправки` это не файл и не команда, но так как у вас сохранен BAT как 1251, ничего и не прочитать... и `pause` добавьте после всех команд в файл чтоб консоль не закрывалась сразу... и пробел `do` и `echo` должен быть

Comment: Знак "<" относится к спецсимволам. Для корректной обработки попробуйте использовать экранирование спецсимволов с помощью тильды:  delims=^< t

Comment: Синтаксический разбор выполнения команды пинг я рекомендую вынести в отдельную процедуру. Тогда вы сможете прерывать её в произвольный момент, чтобы считать только первую строку вывода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Я убрал все символы *(точки)* после %%i

```
Размер буфера отправки=%%i (тут были точки) Время отклика=%%a
```

Без этих *точек*, и с правильной кодировкой как мне подсказали в комментариях. Спасибо тем кто отписался в них и в частности пользователю [Akubik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/268783/akubik), который и дал совет об этих точек